# Line changes color on hover for recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to make the line of a [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line) line chart change color when the user hovers over it. I want to get this working. Here is what I tried, I used handleHover function to determine if the line is active and then used a ternary operator in the stoke prop. See the HandleHover function as well as the "  component.

```
handleHover = (Data, index) => {
  this.setState({
    activeIndex: index,
  });
};

export const colorSchemeFill = [
  'rgba(253, 127, 111, 0.6)',
  'rgba(126, 176, 213, 0.6)',
  'rgba(178, 224, 97, 0.6)',
  'rgba(189, 126, 190, 0.6)',
  'rgba(255, 181, 90, 0.6)',
  'rgba(255, 238, 101, 0.6)',
  'rgba(190, 185, 219, 0.6)',
  'rgba(253, 204, 229, 0.6)',
  'rgba(139, 211, 199, 0.6)',
];

export const ChartWrapper = ({ Metrics, Data, width, height }) => {
  console.log(Data, Metrics);
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width={width} height={height - 70}>
      <LineChart data={Data}>
        <CartesianGrid
          style={{ stroke: 'rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.2)' }}
          vertical={false}
        />
        <XAxis dataKey='date' />
        <Tooltip content={renderTooltipContent}></Tooltip>
        <Brush dataKey='date' height={30} stroke='rgb(33, 37, 41)' />
        {Metrics.map((metric, index) => {
          let orientation;
          if (index % 2 === 0) {
            orientation = 'left';
          } else {
            orientation = 'right';
          }
          return (
            <>
              <YAxis
                domain={['auto', 'auto']}
                yAxisId={metric.APIProperty + '_axis'}
                orientation={orientation}
                tick={{
                  stroke: metric.color,
                  strokeWidth: 1,
                }}
                tickFormatter={(tick) => {
                  return numeral(tick).format('0.00 a');
                }}
                axisLine={{
                  stroke: colorSchemeFill[index % 8],
                  strokeWidth: 1,
                }}>
              </YAxis>
              <Line
                type='monotone'
                yAxisId={metric.APIProperty + '_axis'}
                dataKey={metric.APIProperty}
                strokeWidth={2}
                stroke={
                  index === activeIndex ? 'yellow' : colorSchemeFill[index % 8]
                }
                onMouseOver={() => this.handleHover(Data, index)}
                dot={true}></Line>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In example that you provided, you use function component ChartWrapper and have a handleHover function that is actually outside of this component.

I'm not sure how full code looks like, but currently it's not clear how you pass that data into your ChartWrapper and what is going on with state here.

Provide full example, or just use useState inside of your ChartWrapper component, move your handleHover function into it and try it out.